# when press ctrl + f5 open launch.json and my code is not run what about this problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA9kl.png)

this photo when I was run my dart code
last night ctrl + f5 worked correctly and today happen this problem!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the notification, you should set the `program` value in your `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Dart & Flutter",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "program": "main.dart"
    }
  ]
}
```

You should set the `program` value to the entry file of your Dart program - in your case, it is `main.dart`.

Comment: Do not forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: and i have another question when i closed launch file and again press run button launch file comeback again! why? in the past it's good what's that's reason please can i help me about it ? thanks

Comment: Not sure about this, that's related to VS Code and not Flutter or Dart in general. Just save this configuration file, F5 should work, then.